# Find app uninstalltions in Windows Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have deployed an application to the Windows Store. Is there any way to find out how many of users have uninstalled the app?

Answer (score 0):

The store does not get updated when an app is uninstalled, so you would instead need to consider some other way of measuring it with your analytics (for example, you *might* consider an app uninstalled if it is unused after thirty days for a given [device id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.id.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Comment: How to find the device ID and check whether it is not used?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what Rowland Shaw proposed, you must manually implement some kind of telemetry in your app.

You can do it all by yourself by retrieving the Device ID via the appropriate API (a quick search on the web could help here) and later send that ID to your web service on a periodic basis.

Alternatively you can use third party frameworks, [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/), just to name one, but I don't know if it allows you to track a specific Device ID natively.